# How can I use a ClassVar Literal as a discriminator for Pydantic fields?

Tags: python-typing, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I'd like to have Pydantic fields that are discriminated based on a class variable.

For example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Literal, ClassVar

class Cat(BaseModel):
    animal_type: ClassVar[Literal['cat']] = 'cat'

class Dog(BaseModel):
    animal_type: ClassVar[Literal['dog']] = 'dog'

class PetCarrier(BaseModel):
    contains: Cat | Dog = Field(discriminator='animal_type')
```

But this code throws an exception at import time:

> pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: Model 'Cat' needs a discriminator field for key 'animal_type'

If I remove the `ClassVar` annotations, it works fine, but then `animal_type` is only available as an instance property, which is less convenient in my case.

Can anyone help me use class attributes as discriminators with Pydantic? This is Pydantic version 2.

Comment: What are your expected inputs? If someone give you a `{'name': 'DatCog'}`, how do you tell if it's a `Cat` or a `Dog`?

Comment: By examining the value of the discriminator. This is supported natively in Pydantic https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/usage/types/unions/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions

Comment: The `dict` in my comment has no `animal_type` key. How do you discriminate it?

Comment: Then it's not a valid animal input. I'm not sure what you're getting at? I guess you're trying to point at a need for the discriminator among instance values as input data, but there's no reason we couldn't serialize a class attr discriminator for output and accept it as input. Maybe Pydantic doesn't support this usage, but I don't see any fundamental reason against it.

Comment: By way of example, it's relatively common to see `self.prop = self.prop` as a line in an `__init__()` to transform a class attr into an instance attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. Broadly it seems to me that Pydantic does not support discriminated unions for `ClassVar` literals, but that asks the question, why not?

An important thing to note about `ClassVar`'s, is they don't become regular fields in pydantic (https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/usage/models/#class-vars). In some way they're quite a lot like `PrivateAttr`. They're only accessible via get, they don't feature in models. If we consider your question again but using `PrivateAttr`, it makes sense why this isn't supported:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, PrivateAttr
from typing import Literal

class Cat(BaseModel):
    _animal_type: Literal['cat'] = PrivateAttr(default='cat')

class Dog(BaseModel):
    _animal_type: Literal['dog'] = PrivateAttr(default='dog')

class PetCarrier(BaseModel):
    contains: Cat | Dog = Field(discriminator='_animal_type')
```

`Field` cannot access the discriminator `_animal_type` because it isn't accessible to it - it's a `PrivateAttr`. A discriminator has to be something that is a part of the model - even if instances aren't part of your use case, you have to consider what would happen if someone did make an instance.

Just like `PrivateAttr`, `ClassVar` is a field that's not really part of the model, so it's impossible to use as a discriminator. In Pydantic I would think of `ClassVar` as kind of like a `PrivateAttr` that's publically accessible and can't be altered.